# Why is the strip() function depleting my mustard?

Tags: python, strip

I'm creating a Hot Dog simulator in python, with a class "HotDog".
When I'm formatting the string, if there are 2 condiments, I wrote this code to add it to the string:

```
if len(self.condiments) == 2:
    for i in self.condiments:
        msg = msg + i + " and "
    msg = msg.strip(" and ")
```

If the second condiment is "mustard", the strip() function is taking away the "d" of mustard, so the string prints like this:

```
Raw hot dog with ketchup and mustar.
```

I've used trial and error to find more info, and it seems "d" is the only letter that will disappear, i.e.: mustarg and mustarb will be fine.
Also, it seems to be the "a" of `msg = msg.strip(" and ")` that is causing the problem.
If I only strip "d " or "nd ", mustard will be fine.

Comment: That's what `.strip` is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to do, yes. *"The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped"*.

Comment: How about `' and '.join(self.condiments)`?

Answer (score 1):

That's the documented feature.

> *the characters in the string* will be stripped from the both ends of the string this method is called on

So, if you initially did `a raw hotdog`, then you'd end up with `raw hotdog`

How about instead you used

```
 " and ".join(condiments)
```

> If I only strip "d " or "nd ", mustard will be fine.

But you'd have an `a` at the end of the message, no?

Answer (score 0):

The `strip` method doesn't work the way you seem to expect. Its argument is a sequence of characters that will be removed if they appear in any order (and any number of times) at either end of your string. So when you pass in `" and "`, you're telling it to strip off all spaces, `'a'`, `'n'` and `'d'` characters. Since the `'d'` in `'mustard'` is one of those characters, it will be stripped if it's at the end.

A better way to remove a specific amount of text from the end of a string would be to slice it: `msg = msg[:-5]` will remove the last five characters.

Or you can avoid creating the extra `" and "` in any number of ways, such as using `str.format` or `str.join` (or a combination of the two).

Comment: Or `msg = msg[:-len(" and ")]`